# What is the safest/proper way to implement a thread-safe singleton pattern?

Tags: c#, multithreading, singleton

How do I implement the singleton pattern in C# and ensure that it is thread safe?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Jon Skeet has an [article](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx) on this that covers most of your options.